# How to find liquids with relatively low vapor pressure?

Tags: thermodynamics, evaporation

I want to find some liquids with relatively low vapor pressure whose physical properties could be obtained from NIST database, or a Chemical handbook, or an acknowledged website.

**Specifically, my questions are:**

(1) How do you find a kind of liquids with a certain special property, for example, low vapor pressure?

(2) Could you give me a few volatile liquids with low vapor pressure?

Comment: How can volatile liquids have low vapor pressure? What is your definition of "volatile"?

Comment: @Zero the vapor pressure is low when compared with other liquid. For example, $CCl_2H_2$ has relatively high vapor pressure compare with methanol at the same temperature when they saturated. By "volatile", I want to say the liquids are evaporating to be a saturation state.

Comment: Did you try Wolfram Alpha?  [Here is an example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=low+vapor+pressure+liquids)

Comment: @LouisB, great! Why I did't figure out that great engine!

Comment: What about vacuum pump oils which have a low vapour pressure but they are not volatile? CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics.